# Irregularity css positioning in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

[When i click the Change text title has to be changed randomly in demo](http://cruisear.com/demo/1/). However, if i click change text with Chrome browser random text will interlock with each other like in picture. How can i prevent this irregularity?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function next(tags)
{
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'ajax_next_track.php?tags=' + tags;
    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) 
        {   
           var return_data = hr.responseText;
           console.log(return_data);
           jsonObj = JSON.parse(return_data);
           document.getElementById("artist_name").innerHTML = jsonObj.artist_name;
           document.getElementById("track_name").innerHTML = jsonObj.track_name;
           document.getElementById("name").title = 'play '+jsonObj.artist_name+' - '+jsonObj.track_name+' radio';

        else
        {

        }
    }

    document.getElementById("track_name").innerHTML = 'loading...';
    document.getElementById("artist_name").innerHTML = '';
    hr.send(null); 
}
```

---

```
#playPauseOutDiv {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px;
    z-index: 4;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}


#artist_name {
        position: relative;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        float:left;
        font-size: 1.9em;
        font-weight:600;
}

#track_name {
        position:relative;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        float:left;
        margin-left:15px;
        top:6px;
}


#artist_track {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    height: 35px;
    font-family:"Arial",Georgia,Serif;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:0px;
    color: #221E1F;

}
```

Comment: You'll want to figure out what's causing this, and then fix it.

Comment: I would help. But honestly...... I don't want to read through all your code to figure out what's going on. Please post only relevant parts instead of an entire dump.

Comment: the new loaded text has smaller width and the text doesnt seem to fit.

Comment: WTF is that bunch of classes at the beggining of your CSS?!?!

Comment: Without reading through all of your code, I'm guessing you removed some of the text from the page flow using position: fixed.

Comment: I have posted all codes. Sorry, i have simplified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is atrocious.  Stop floating everything.

`#artist_name` should not be `float:left` it should likely be `display:inline; vertical-align:baseline`.
`#track_name` should not be `float:left`,`position:relative`, and `top:6px` it should likely be `display:inline;vertical-align:baseline`.

That fixes your chrome issue.

Other things you SHOULD change:
`#artist_name` and `#track_name` shouldn't be divs, they are text, and should probably be spans (Which are automatically display:inline).

I typically wouldn't make playPauseOutDiv floating.  I would make it `display:inline-block` or `position:absolute;top:0;left:0`, but seeing as it actually does float left, this is actually the intended purpose of float, so there you are actually using it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, i am in progress :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using `float: left` and `position: relative` on `#track_name` and `#artist_name`. Try losing the `position` and changing both the `#track_name` and `#artist_name` to `display: inline-block` and adding the styling that you're looking for. You also need to set `width` as currently they are sitting on `0`.

**EDIT**
Change `display` to `inline` and you don't need to worry about width!